# How to catch a playwright freeze?

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

I have a script in Playwright 1.23.1 with Python 3.10.2 running in Ubuntu LTS 20.4 to extract data from a page, the scripts run for about an hour because it is a lot of data. The problem is that sometimes the execution freezes and I can't catch it and I have to give the SIGINT sign (CTRL + C) to stop the execution. I don't know if it is a problem of Playwright or it is of the page that it is browsing. This page is really not that good, it's slow and have some problems in general.

My code is something like this:

```
from playwright.sync_api import TimeoutError as PlaywrightTimeoutError
from playwright.sync_api import Error as PlaywrightError


with sync_playwright() as spw:
    # connect to the page
    browser, page = connect(spw)
    # sign in with credentials
    sign_in(username, page)
    data_code = 1
    while True:
        try:
            # Extract the data from the page using playwright methods
            # including select_option, frame_locator, evaluate, click, and reload
            end_signal = extract_data(page, data_code)
            if end_signal:
                break
        except (TimeoutError, PlaywrightTimeoutError, PlaywrightError) as e:
            print(f"Error is: {e}")
            page.reload(timeout=90000, wait_until='domcontentloaded')
        data_code += 1
    print("Exit cycle")
```

That's the basic structure of my code, the problem is that sometimes when trying to use `click`, `select_option`, or `reloading` the execution freezes. There are some prints inside `extract_data` but they don't appear, and sometimes *print(f"Error is: {e}")* does not print, so it does reach it, therefore, my conclusion is that the execution is freezed.

I have researched a little about Playwright debug, but in general I can't find the problem, and this error happens sometimes not always, so I can't repliacte it for a proper debug with playwights. The logs at least let me identify where it freezes, but nothing else so far.

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: That 'run for about an hour because it is a lot of data' is a tad strange. Are you sure you are approaching the problem the right way? What sort of data? What sort of data transformation? Are you sure you are accessing the right data sources? Are you sure this is appropriate for a  sync job? Can you provide a minimum work example, so someone can help you?

Comment: The hour is also because it has high timeout values because the page is really slow, and some sleeps in order that the execution seams more human. The data extraction is great, mainly text. The only thing I'm not sure of what you asked is if it is a sync job. I'll check it out.

I can't share the page, and either way you need credentials to log in, so I can't do much in that aspect (which I know makes it harder to answer this problem)

Comment: It must be a sync job, I need the answer of the page in every step to asure I'm extraction the data correctly (which I am excepte when the execution freezes).